# how to merge multiple list base weight

Tags: java, algorithm

Let's say, for example, that there are three lists, `A`，`B` and `C`. Their weights are 2, 3 and 5 respectively.  The resulting list is then the result of taking elements from each of the lists, where you can take up to that list's weight of elements from it before moving onto the next (cycling back to the first list after the final one) until all elements are consumed.

For the list's mentioned above this could look something like:

```
list A:{a,a,a,a,a}; (weight 2)
list B:{b,b,b,b,b}; (weight 3)
list C:{c,c,c,c,c}; (weight 5)

result is:{a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,c,c,a,a,b,b,a}.
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problem are you facing?

Comment: I don't know how to implement it efficiently@Amongalen

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a sublist with the size of the weight from each list until all lists are empty. Before you get the subList you have to check if the list still has enough elements, if not then you can just take the rest of the list.

```
public class Solution {

    private static final String A = "a";
    private static final String B = "b";
    private static final String C = "c";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> c = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        a.addAll(List.of(A, A, A, A, A));
        b.addAll(List.of(B, B, B, B, B));
        c.addAll(List.of(C, C, C, C, C));

        int weightA = 2;
        int weightB = 3;
        int weightC = 5;

        boolean done = false;

    while (!done) {
        weightA = a.size() < weightA ? a.size() : weightA;
        List<String> subList = a.subList(0, weightA);
        result.addAll(subList);
        subList.clear();

        weightB = b.size() < weightB ? b.size() : weightB;
        subList = b.subList(0, weightB);
        result.addAll(subList);
        subList.clear();

        weightC = c.size() < weightC ? c.size() : weightC;
        subList = c.subList(0, weightC);
        result.addAll(subList);
        subList.clear();

        done = a.isEmpty() && b.isEmpty() && c.isEmpty();
    }

    System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: subList is a view of list,so result will all the (0,weight) of list.

Comment: that's why you call `clear()` after you add the sublist to your result list. The clear will also remove the sublist from your original list because lists are mutable.
Is the code not working for you?